# Edit Zoomed Images displayed in HTML5 canvas element

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am using HTML5 canvas to display an image with zoomin/out feature. It works fine. However, i also need to edit the image. For instance on mouse click, I need to replace a certain size of grid in the image ( size is dynamic, not always fixed). So i am using 
`context.putImageData(imgData, x, y)`, where `imgData` is a grid of 10*10 ( for instance) to be replaced at x, y location.

This  works fine. But when I zoomin/out, all my image edits disappear. I think the reason being , putImageData, replace only in memory image on the canvas element, and never updates original image source.

I am wondering how to overcome this issue ? I suppose I need to edit the orignal image and then draw it using `drawImage()` instead of using `context.putImageData()` directly.

But how do I do it ?

//@ startup
//currentScale =1.0

```
var photo = new Image();
photo.src = "./Ship1.png";
photo.addEventListener('load', eventPhotoLoaded, false); 
function drawImage()
{

this.context.drawImage(photo, 0, 0, photo.width,photo.height, 0, 0, photo.width * currentScale,  photo.height* currentScale);
}
```

//It properly displays the image

// Onmouse click

```
theCanvas.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
var rect = this.theCanvas.getBoundingClientRect();
x = evt.clientX - rect.left;
y = evt.clientY - rect.top;

//newGird is an array of cells containing R,G,B and Alpha values
context.putImageData(newGird, x, y)
```

//The above code correctly updates the canvas image at point x,y with the newGrid. Looks great so far.

//have button for zoomin/out. And on button click, I change the value of currentScale and call drawImage() method. Zoom in/out is done properly, but as expected the changes done by putImageData() are overwritten by original image, because those changes were never saved back to the image.

Comment: A working bin would certainly help others attempt to come up with a solution. That, or post more of your code.

Comment: sounds like a transformation issue…?

Comment: I added the code snippet.  Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: @philipp, can you please elaborate on transformation issue ? What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: I even tried 
    this.context.scale(currentScale,currentScale)
    this.context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

Since img is pointing to original image, my edits done via putImageData() are lost.

Comment: Can please be more specific? What do you mean by: »those changes were never saved back to the image«? Is the bug happening when scaling the canvas? How do you want to save changes? What is the expected behavior?

Comment: Here are the steps

1. Display Image using drawImage function
2. Edit image using putImageData
3. ZoomInOut using drawImage function. So, at step 3 changes done in step 2 are lost

Answer (score 0):

This problem is solved now. In step 3, scaling can done by changing canvas.style.width and canvas.style.height instead of calling drawImage again. So, It works fine. Thanks philipp and yoursweater